# How to perform dynamic partition based on row count in dataFram for a column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.6

I am trying to partition a input files based on `accountId` But this partition has be done only if dataFrames contains more than 1000 records. The `accountId` is a dynamic integer that could not be uknown. Consider the following code below

```
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("input")
lines.print()

lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val count = rdd.count()
  if (count > 0) {
    val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
    val filteredDF = df.filter(df("accountId")==="3")
    if (filteredDF.count() > 1000) {
      df.write.partitionBy("accountId").format("json").save("output")
    }
  }
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

But the above code partitions all accountId which is not needed.

1. I want to find the count for each `accountId` in the dataframe.
2. If records for each accountId exceeds 1000, then write the partitioned information into output source.

For example, If the input file has 1500 records for accountId=1 and 10 records for accountId=2, then partition filtered dataframe based on accountId=1 into output source and keep accountId=2 records in memmory.

How to achieve this using spark-streaming?

Answer (score 1):

Should'd you be doing

```
filteredDF.write.partitionBy("accountId").format("json").save("output")
```

instead of

```
df.write.partitionBy("accountId").format("json").save("output")
```